# Bourne shell: reading multiple lines of stdin

Tags: shell, integer, sh, stdin

I am new to Bourne shells and was curious about reading stdin on multiple lines/that includes newline.

IN: For example, if someone types in

```
1
  3         #only ignore whitespace
5.3         #ignore floating point number all together
```

I could have it read them and echo them on separate lines. My goal is to also *ignore floating point numbers (integers only!) and ignore whitespace*.

OUT: My ideal output would calculate the average (example with above input)

```
1
2
```

So far I can read stdin and echo it back if it is on one line and limited to a hardcoded value (should be whenever user stops with Ctrl-D).

```
#! /bin/sh

read a b c

echo "$a";
echo "$b";
echo "$c";
```

Comment: Is it for an assignment where you're stuck using sh? Because bash is a superset of sh and has  some extremely convenient string operators and a better read function.  Most companies/engineers I know switched to bash for most of their basic shell scripting on UNIX awhile ago.  It's the default shell on Linux login. And even Solaris.

Comment: @1sand0s Yup, don't have a choice with shell this time! I prefer using bash and while I don't love it, I'm more comfortable with tcsh than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is been a while, but the following should obtain a `sum` and `average` for only integer input:

```
#!/bin/sh

sum=0;
cnt=0

while read line
do

    case "$line" in

        *[.]*  )
            continue
            ;;

        [0-9]* ) 
            sum=`expr "$sum" + "$line"`
            cnt=`expr "$cnt" + 1`
            ;;
    esac

done

printf "\nThe sum is '%s', cnt is '%s' the average is '%s'\n\n", "$sum" "$cnt" `expr $sum / $cnt`
```

**Output**

```
$ printf "1\n 3\n5.3\n" | sh bourne_sum.sh

The sum is '4', cnt is '2' the average is '2'
```

**Input in a File**

```
$ cat dat/bsum.txt
1
 3
5.3
```

Simple redirection will do:

```
$ sh bourne_sum.sh <dat/bsum.txt

The sum is '4', cnt is '2' the average is '2'
```

---

**Modified to output on 1 line**

```
#!/bin/sh

sum=0;
cnt=0

while read line
do

    case "$line" in

        *[.]*  )
            printf " 0"
            continue
            ;;

        [0-9]* ) 
            sum=`expr "$sum" + "$line"`
            cnt=`expr "$cnt" + 1`
            printf " %s" `expr $sum / $cnt`
            ;;
    esac

done

printf "\n"

# printf "\nThe sum is '%s', cnt is '%s' the average is '%s'\n\n" "$sum" "$cnt" `expr $sum / $cnt`
```

**Output**

```
$ printf "1\n3\n5\n4.4\n" | sh bourne_sum.sh
 1 2 3 0
```

---

### Responding to ONLY Integers

```
#!/bin/sh

sum=0;
cnt=0

while read line
do

    if [ $line -eq $line 2>/dev/null ]
    then

        sum=`expr "$sum" + "$line"`
        cnt=`expr "$cnt" + 1`
        printf " %s" `expr $sum / $cnt`

    fi

done

printf "\n"
```

**Output**

```
$ printf "1\n3\n5\n4.4\n'2 3'\n" | sh bourne_sum.sh

 1 2 3
```

Comment: While this reads it in correctly, it does not let me print out as desired. How do I extract from how it reads so that, if the input was, each number of a new line:  1
     3
     5
     4.4. It would output 
     1
     2
     3
     0  since ignores 4.4 (not an int)

Comment: See addition to answer. It just depends what you want. All you need do is move the `printf` statements to produce the desired output.  Let me know if you have more questions.  (Oh wait, I see you still want the average and continued sum.. Hold on.. (fixed)

Comment: Yes, how can I have it ignore cases where it's not just an integer? I want it to ignore completely something like '5 6' on one line (only one integer allowed per line or '5 hello text', just to skip over those/have it output 0 like it did for the float.

Comment: You can add a test `[ $var -eq $var ]` which only succeeds when `$var` is an `int` and will fail for all other cases. You probably want to redirect the output to `stderr`. e.g. `if [ $var -eq $var 2>/dev/null ]; then printf "%d is an int\n" $var; else  printf "%d is NOT an int\n" $var; fi`